# where does the unit tangent vector formula come from?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

if we have a parametric curve $\overrightarrow r(t)=x(t)\hat i + y(t)\hat j+z(t) \hat k$,
how can we derive from it the formula for unit tangent vector which is:

$\overrightarrow T(t)=\frac{\overrightarrow r^\prime(t)}{||r^\prime(t)||}=\frac{x^\prime(t)\hat i + y^\prime(t)\hat j+z^\prime(t) \hat k}{{||r^\prime(t)||}}$

**in short, I need a proof for unit tangent vector formula.**

definition of unit tangent vector from [calculus volume 3](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-3/pages/3-2-calculus-of-vector-valued-functions):
Let C be a curve defined by a vector-valued function $\overrightarrow r$, and assume that $\overrightarrow r′(t)$ exists when $t=t_0$. A tangent vector $\overrightarrow v$ at $t=t_0$ is any vector such that, when the tail of the vector is placed at point $\overrightarrow r(t_0)$ on the graph, vector $\overrightarrow v$ is tangent to curve C. Vector $\overrightarrow r′(t_0)$ is an example of a tangent vector at point $t=t_0$. Furthermore, assume that $\overrightarrow r′(t)≠0$. The principal unit tangent vector at t is defined to be

$\overrightarrow T(t)=\frac{\overrightarrow r^\prime(t)}{||r^\prime(t)||}$

Comment: What's your definition of tangent vector?

Comment: the definition was added.

Comment: There is no proof. This is not a theorem, it's a definition. This is like asking for the proof of what a prime number is. Your definition of "tangent" is also useless - you use the very word "tangent" in said definition.

Comment: if that's the case I change my question. how can we understand that $\overrightarrow r'(t)$ is tangent to curve $\overrightarrow r(t)$.